# Specify memory usage limit in Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod Powershell

Tags: powershell, powerbi

I am refreshing PowerBi datasets from PowerShell using the Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod cmdlet.

My URL is of the following form:

$processURL = [https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/{someGuid}/refreshes](https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/%7BsomeGuid%7D/refreshes)

I initiate the call using this syntax:

Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url $processURL -Method Post -Body($datasetGUID)

We are encountering an error recently "Resource governing: This operation was canceled because there wasn’t enough memory to finish running it. Either increase the memory of the Premium capacity where this dataset is hosted or reduce the memory footprint of your dataset....."

My question is simply:

Am I able to specify a flag or query string that will allow me to specify the memory usage for a refresh so that we do not encounter this error?

Answer (score 0):

> Am I able to specify a flag or query string that will allow me to specify the memory usage for a refresh so that we do not encounter this error?

Not directly.  By default a refresh needs to build a separate copy of the dataset in memory while the old one is still serving query requests.

The easiest thing is to reduce the maxParallelism of the refresh to refresh fewer tables/partitions at a time.

```
"maxParallelism": 2,
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/asynchronous-refresh

If your large tables aren't partitioned, this might not help.

You can also use [Query scale-out with manual sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/service-premium-scale-out-sync-replica) to enable you to clear the Read/Write copy of the dataset, refresh it, and then synchronize it to the reader node(s).